# Passing a value from child to parent react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The child

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ref, update, get,} from "firebase/database";
import { database } from '../../utils/firebase';
import './Card.css';



function Card(props) {
    const [uid, setUID] = useState(props.uid);
    function completeCard() {
        const userRef = ref(database, 'users/' + uid);
          get(userRef).then((snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            var completedMissions = data["challenges"];
            completedMissions.push(props.cardID);
            console.log(completedMissions);
            const updates = {};
            updates['/users/' + uid +'/challenges'] = completedMissions;
            update(ref(database), updates);
          });
          
    }
    return(
        <div className="card">
            <h1>{props.name}</h1>
            <p>{props.description}</p>
            <button onClick={completeCard}>Completar</button>
            <button>+Info</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Card;
```

The parent

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth, database } from '../../utils/firebase';
import { ref, get} from "firebase/database";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

//Components
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';
import Card from './Card';

function Dashboard() {
    const [uid, setUID] = useState("");
    const [completedChallenges, setCompletedChallenges] = useState([]);
    const [displayCards, setDisplayCard] = useState([]);

    const [updateChallenges, setUpdateChallenges] = useState(false);

    function setCards() {
      const userRef = ref(database, 'challenges');
          get(userRef).then((snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            var currentDisplayCards = [];
            for(let i =1; i <= 10; i++){
              if(currentDisplayCards.length == 5) {break;}
              if(completedChallenges.indexOf(parseInt(i)) == -1){
                currentDisplayCards.push(data[i]);
              }
            }
            setDisplayCard(currentDisplayCards);
          });
    }

    function setPage() {
          setUID(auth.currentUser["uid"]);
          const userRef = ref(database, 'users/' + uid);
          get(userRef).then((snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            setCompletedChallenges(data["challenges"]);
            setCards();
          });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
          setPage();
        } else {
          return <Redirect to= '/'/>
        }
      });
    }, [uid]);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
            <h2> Your missions </h2>
            {displayCards.map((card) => (
              <Card 
              uid={uid} 
              key={card.key} 
              cardID={card.key} 
              name={card.name} 
              description={card.description}/>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

How can i pass a value from the child when the user clicks on the button and calls the function completeCard() so I can set the state of completedChallenges to true in the parent? I saw other similar questions but I wasn't able to implement it in this case, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The most common approach is that you define your onClick callback for the `Card` component in the parent `Dashboard` and pass it as a prop to the child.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If your parent and child components are isolated, which means they interact with each other but not with other, then Context API is a good choice.

This will allow the parent and child components communicate on the same states.

Let's a React context:

```js
const DashboardContext = createContext({});
```

Your parent component:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [uid, setUID] = useState("");
  const [completedChallenges, setCompletedChallenges] = useState([]);
  const [displayCards, setDisplayCard] = useState([]);

  const [updateChallenges, setUpdateChallenges] = useState(false);

  // Other effects

  return (
    <DashboardContext.Provider value={{ // pass states and setStates here}}>
      {// ... }
    </DashboardContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

In child component:

```
const Card = (props) => {
  const dashboardCtx = useContext(DashboardContext);
  // or you can use destructuring assignment, choose one
  const { uid, setUID }  = useContext(DashboardContext);

  return (
   // ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to resolve...

1- Context API, if you want access the state from both components.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
2- You may keep the function in the parent component and pass as a props.
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.